# Input Until Non-Word Character in C, Like Java's \W

Tags: c, input, cpu-word, char, delimited

I want to input words from a file which are delimited by anything that isn't a letter. Is there an easy way to do this in C similar to using the \W predefined character classes in Java?

How should I approach this?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out the functions `fgetc()`, `isalpha()`, possibly `ungetc()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Character classes in general and \W specifically really aren't related to Java at all.  They're just part of regular expression support, which is available for many languages, including GNU C.  See [GNU C library Regular Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [`is_`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/) family of functions defined in `<ctype.h>`.

For instance, `isalpha()` will tell you if something is an alphabetic character.  `isspace()` will tell you if something is whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fscanf` (provided you're guaranteed a max length of word)

```
char temp_str[1000];
char temp_w[1000]
while(fscanf(file, "%[a-zA-Z]%[^a-zA-Z]", temp_str, temp_w) != EOF) {
  printf("STR: %s\n", temp_str);
}
```

**Edit:** this should do the trick, `temp_str` will hold the sequence of letters and `temp_w` will hold the delimiting characters inbetween

Comment: Thank you very much sir. One question, should it be z instead of b?

Comment: Yea it should have been z and I had one other problem.  The above will work as long as the file always starts with a sequence of letters.  If not, or if you need something more robust you may want to use getc() and isalpha()